# Error socket binding to ip can't stop http server

Tags: python, httpserver

```
    s = socket.socket()

    try:
        host = "http://{}".format(IP) + ":" + "{}".format(PORT) + "/index.html"
        s.bind((host, PORT))
```

this is where the error comes whatever i do it is always prints Error
BTW trying to connect to a simple http server

```
    except:
        print("Error")

    while True:
        try:
            s.listen(5)
            conn, addr = s.accept()

            print("[+] IP Logged" + str(addr[0]))

        except:
            pass
            print("Exiting...")
            sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Catching and hiding errors in this way is a bad idea. Add "raise" in the except-block to see the full traceback. And show it as properly formatted text in the question if you don't understand the error.

Comment: Like so what would the except be?

Comment: In this case in the first except-block which currently only contains `print("Error")`

Comment: like a function:
 try:
  host = "http://{}".format(IP) + ":" + "{}".format(PORT) + "/index.html"
  s.bind((host, PORT))
 except:
  raise()
  print("Error")

Comment: No. You should read the tutorial part about exception handling: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: its the getadrrinfo thats failing its because i still have the http server running so it cant bind!